# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, iis

I am getting this error in my .aspx page (check below... of this statement completion) only if there are more records like>100 in Asp.Net GridView (and the grid is in UpdatePanel) and the application is hosted in Windows Server 2008 as well as Windows Server 2003 but getting the error only in Windows Server 2008. It is working fine in 2003. I tried all the methods but not able to resolve as I am not able to trace the exact error that is causing the problem.

why the same Application behaving differently in Windows Server 2008.

```
POST xxxURL 500 (Internal Server Error) ScriptResource.axd?d=AXh2_DFzEqWB7gi9yJBKBcPGsLvQFV5Y59KkAic6jJXRcATzRXABjIRMoeZZHAiaB3gWmR1lxbgXFF…:6979
XMLHttpExecutor$executeRequest ScriptResource.axd?d=AXh2_DFzEqWB7gi9yJBKBcPGsLvQFV5Y59KkAic6jJXRcATzRXABjIRMoeZZHAiaB3gWmR1lxbgXFF…:6979
_WebRequestManager$executeRequest ScriptResource.axd?d=AXh2_DFzEqWB7gi9yJBKBcPGsLvQFV5Y59KkAic6jJXRcATzRXABjIRMoeZZHAiaB3gWmR1lxbgXFF…:7367
WebRequest$invoke ScriptResource.axd?d=AXh2_DFzEqWB7gi9yJBKBcPGsLvQFV5Y59KkAic6jJXRcATzRXABjIRMoeZZHAiaB3gWmR1lxbgXFF…:7538
PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmit ScriptResource.axd?d=sPyFKwkQf4yNnEeHF3vesu1-Vx42gXXIaL3ecCYu_pKKVTxGyBu7LwmcrodPzJ-ewE4qiv3kinx0OV…:1385
(anonymous function) ScriptResource.axd?d=AXh2_DFzEqWB7gi9yJBKBcPGsLvQFV5Y59KkAic6jJXRcATzRXABjIRMoeZZHAiaB3gWmR1lxbgXFF…:628
browserHandler ScriptResource.axd?d=AXh2_DFzEqWB7gi9yJBKBcPGsLvQFV5Y59KkAic6jJXRcATzRXABjIRMoeZZHAiaB3gWmR1lxbgXFF…:4886
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500 ScriptResource.axd?d=AXh2_DFzEqWB7gi9yJBKBcPGsLvQFV5Y59KkAic6jJXRcATzRXABjIRMoeZZHAiaB3gWmR1lxbgXFF…:847
Error$create ScriptResource.axd?d=AXh2_DFzEqWB7gi9yJBKBcPGsLvQFV5Y59KkAic6jJXRcATzRXABjIRMoeZZHAiaB3gWmR1lxbgXFF…:847
PageRequestManager$_createPageRequestManagerServerError ScriptResource.axd?d=sPyFKwkQf4yNnEeHF3vesu1-Vx42gXXIaL3ecCYu_pKKVTxGyBu7LwmcrodPzJ-ewE4qiv3kinx0OV…:765
PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmitCompleted ScriptResource.axd?d=sPyFKwkQf4yNnEeHF3vesu1-Vx42gXXIaL3ecCYu_pKKVTxGyBu7LwmcrodPzJ-ewE4qiv3kinx0OV…:1411
(anonymous function) ScriptResource.axd?d=AXh2_DFzEqWB7gi9yJBKBcPGsLvQFV5Y59KkAic6jJXRcATzRXABjIRMoeZZHAiaB3gWmR1lxbgXFF…:628
(anonymous function) ScriptResource.axd?d=AXh2_DFzEqWB7gi9yJBKBcPGsLvQFV5Y59KkAic6jJXRcATzRXABjIRMoeZZHAiaB3gWmR1lxbgXFF…:4338
raise ScriptResource.axd?d=AXh2_DFzEqWB7gi9yJBKBcPGsLvQFV5Y59KkAic6jJXRcATzRXABjIRMoeZZHAiaB3gWmR1lxbgXFF…:7429
WebRequest$completed ScriptResource.axd?d=AXh2_DFzEqWB7gi9yJBKBcPGsLvQFV5Y59KkAic6jJXRcATzRXABjIRMoeZZHAiaB3gWmR1lxbgXFF…:7433
XMLHttpExecutor._onReadyStateChange ScriptResource.axd?d=AXh2_DFzEqWB7gi9yJBKBcPGsLvQFV5Y59KkAic6jJXRcATzRXABjIRMoeZZHAiaB3gWmR1lxbgXFF…:6857
```

Comment: What's the inner exception? It can have soemthing to do with request lenght.

Comment: I think there is problem with Update Panel or Ajax and there is no inner Exception as it is a custom error which cannot be handled.

Comment: Set the maxRequestLenght entry of web.config to a high value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi JotaBe ...I increased the maxrequested length value to the highest possible value but still no progress.